# Displaying search result from the form using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have simple form and script which takes input data and calls rotten tomatoes API and displays results. If I don't use `$('#submitid').click(function()` and var query is hard coded results are displayed fine. If I just use `$('#submitid').click(function() {})` in conjunction with alert,   form data is displayed. However in current state nothing is displayed. Any help is appreciated.

```
<form action="">
    <input  type="text" id='myid' />
    <input value="Search" type="submit" id="submitid" />
</form>

<script>
    $('#submitid').click(function () {
        var query = $('#myid').val();
        var apikey = "my_api_key_sample";
        var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";

        // construct the uri with our apikey
        var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/movies.json?apikey=' + apikey;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // send off the query
            $.ajax({
                url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: searchCallback
            });
        });

        // callback for when we get back the results
        function searchCallback(data) {
            $(document.body).append(
                'Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + query
            );
            var movies = data.movies;
            $.each(movies, function (index, movie) {
                var mydata += //code for appending my data 
            });

            //displaying mydata on div with id result
            $('#result').html(mydata);
        }
    })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="someform">
    <input  type="text" id='myid'>
    <input value="Search" type="submit" id="submitid">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#someform").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: searchCallback
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: you are welcome. you could always improve your code buy making use of other jQuery available functions such as serialize - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. Also I would appreciate if you could explain why I need  return false;

Comment: To stop the form submission. jQuery Docs: "Now when the form is submitted, the message is alerted. This happens prior to the actual submission, so we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler." - http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Oh ok, would I be able to do same thing by including return false; inside the actual form, onclick="return false;"

Comment: Yes but I dont recommend using inline event handlers when you have jQuery already on the page.

Answer (score 0):

`var mydata += //code for appending my data`

You need to actually finish this line or comment it out completely. Also, at the end you have `} }) })` which should be  `} });`.

Comment: I removed the code for simplicity sake, it is working fine however. Changing the brackets doesn't affect the script.